# Hibernate multiple object update in same session

Tags: java, hibernate, object, orm, persistent

Using Hibernate I need to update multiple objects  by calling for eg. updateDetails() function shown below:

```
function updateDetails(){   
        Session session = this.getSessionFactory().openSession();           
        Employee emp=(Employee )session.load(Employee.class, empId);
        emp.salary(2000);
        Account acc=(Account)session.load(Account.class, accId);
        account.setTotal(2000);
        Transaction tx=session.beginTransaction();      
        session.update(emp);
        session.update(acc);
        tx.commit();
        result=true;
        session.close();
```

}

what is the best way of doing this ?

does Updating multiple objects of same or different type in same session will cause any problem in hibernate?

Comment: Usually, you open the transaction first, then you load and modify the objects, then you commit the transaction. Calls to `session.update(...)` are not necessary then.

Comment: That's the whole point of using an ORM like Hibernate, to make it easier to work with more complicated object hierarchies! You should really go through the online documentation at least partly to figure out what you actually use it for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not. You can do that. Hibernate allows.

Since you are using Transaction management the answer is depends on your context. If you want to save both Objects regardless of saving another make them update in individual transactions.

If you want to save the whole info successfully and want to revert everything if any of the update fail keep them in the current format.